# GPS Tracker Highly Fluctuating points

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

Hello I am developing a realtime gps tracker using [this](https://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/) library

It gets data from GPS satellites in a period of time..if no gps results is received it then request from cell towers/wifi in a period of time also. My problem is..My gps location is fluctuating so bad. Here is a photo below:

[image]

**Please if anyone there has used this library. Or can recommend to me how to ged rid of this fluctuations. Please help me out..Thanks**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPS can fluctuate when the device moves slowly or stands still.
Switching betweeen GPS and Network Location is not a good idea, (network will introduce jumps of e.g up to 1000m or eveen more)
If you have GPS always use GPS.

If fluctuations are caused by bad GPS signal, you can check the `Location.getHoricontalAccuracy()`: ignore the location if the value is > 30m and you are using GPS only.

If fluctuation is caused by slow movement or stand still, make sure this is the case and ask again for that specific topic, or search SO.

Comment: Hello @AlexWein Thank you for your response. Yes your correct, I have decided to eliminate the celltower requests. That is really the 90% factor that cause fluctuations. I switched into pure gps request and control the accuracy of the points..it improved alot. Thanks

Comment: hi @icaneatclouds if possible can you post your code because I am having the same situation and want to know how did you achieved...